# SSIS Pass parameter value to stored procedure that sends email

Tags: html, sql-server, ssis

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and SSIS.

My scenario: I have a SSIS project that checks for files - the path is stored in a package parameter called `FilePath`.

If no files are found, it triggers a SQL Server stored procedure (`SP_EmailNoFiles`) that in turn sends an email (due to company network policy the SSIS Server cannot relay emails, hence I'm using a stored procedure in the SQL Server to send emails).

My question: is it possible to pass the value of the package parameter `FilePath` to the `SP_EmailNoFiles` stored procedure so it can appear in the body?

Steps I have performed:

- Created "Execute SQL Task" to call `SP_EmailNoFiles` when there are no files
- Within the parameter mapping, I added the variable `$Package::FilePath`, data type = `NVARCHAR` and parameter name = 0
- Within the `SP_EmailNoFiles` stored procedure, I declared the `FilePath` and set the value to `?`
- However, SQL Server doesn't like this and states:

> Incorrect syntax near '?'.

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @ProfileName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Recipients NVARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @Subject NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @FilePath NVARCHAR(255)

SET @ProfileName = 'zzzzzz'
SET @Recipients = 'me@test.com'
SET @Subject = 'source file missing' 
SET @FilePath = ?

-- Build Email Body ---
DECLARE @Body NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Body =
'<html>
<body>
  <table class="outer">
    <tr>
      <td class="header">
        <h3>' + @Subject + '</h3>
        blah blah blah no files detected <br>
        Check the folder path. ' + @FilePath + '<br><br>
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>' +
        '<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
</body>
</html>'

-- Send Mail -----
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
                @profile_name = @ProfileName,  
                @recipients = @Recipients,  
                @body = @Body,  
                @subject = @Subject,
                @body_format = 'HTML';
```

Is what I want possible? Just to recap I want to pass the value of `FilePath` into the body of the HTML email that is created in stored procedure `SP_EmailNoFiles`.

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the tip! what about sp without the underscore?

Comment: It's **just** the `sp_` prefix that's the problem - anything else is OK - including just `sp` (without the underscore)

Comment: @marc_s ok, thanks agian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create this as a stored procedure (lets call it usp_invoke_message) which should be invoked through a call from the execute sql task that will pass in a value for filepath. In TSQL there the only variables are ones that start with an at (@) sign. The question mark in only used in a SQL Task in SSIS.

```
create procedure usp_invoke_message 
@filepath nvarchar(255)
as
begin

set nocount on
DECLARE @ProfileName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Recipients NVARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @Subject NVARCHAR(255)

SET @ProfileName = 'zzzzzz'
SET @Recipients = 'me@test.com'
SET @Subject = 'source file missing' 


-- Build Email Body ---
DECLARE @Body NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Body =
'<html>
<body>
  <table class="outer">
    <tr>
      <td class="header">
        <h3>' + @Subject + '</h3>
        blah blah blah no files detected <br>
        Check the folder path. ' + @FilePath + '<br><br>
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>' +
        '<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
</body>
</html>'

-- Send Mail -----
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
                @profile_name = @ProfileName,  
                @recipients = @Recipients,  
                @body = @Body,  
                @subject = @Subject,
                @body_format = 'HTML';

 end
```

Comment: I've already got a Stored Procedure doing this. Do you mean execute all the above directly within the SSIS 'Execute SQL Task'?

Comment: just the opposite. Please look at my stored procedure. I used a passed in parameter and no '?' in the proc.

Comment: I still receive the message: Incorrect syntax near '?' and there is a red line under the question mark

Comment: deleted line where @filepath is set to ?